# Link to Bitchute Video at Specific Starting Time

Tags: youtube, video, video-streaming, video-download, facebook-videos

In youtube, you can link to a video at a specific starting time by adding query string parameters, like `?t=23m3s`, to the end of the URL.

How can this be done with [bitchute](https://www.bitchute.com/) videos?

Comment: Any news? I really would like a (general) solution for this.

Comment: @ThePhi On Dec 29, 2020, Jon at bitchute support said "This is something we are considering but we don't yet have a timeframe for this". If more people would request this at support@bitchute.com, maybe they'll put more priority on it. Here's their [contact page](https://support.bitchute.com/policy/contact/).

Comment: Mail sent! Thanks.

Comment: I've very disappointed that Bitchute still hasn't implemented this (seemingly) simple request. Multiple people have requested this, but it never gets done.

Comment: Its going on 4 years, and Bitchute still hasn't granted this simple user-request. Over that time, there's no telling how many URLs (for bitchute) that I have not sent, just because I cannot send a link that starts a particular time within the video. I cannot expect the recipient of my link to watch an entire 2 hour video just to discover the 30 seconds of that video I'm really meaning for them to see. Each time I send a link I have to send the timestamp separately. In YouTube, you can just right-click on the video and create a URL for an exact timestamp within that video.

Comment: Very disappointing indeed. I've switched to Odysee.com which already has this feature.